# How can a different set of columns be defined for grouping rows in TanStack Table (previously react-table)?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, tanstack

Given a table of budget line items, I would like to group them by year where each year grouping should display the year and the aggregate amount of the line items as in this screenshot:
[example datatable with custom grouping rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzy8h.png)

Is it possible to get the "grouping row" to render differently from the detail rows so that it can match the screenshot?

This is a minimal reproduction of what I've been able to figure out:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
    ColumnDef,
    useReactTable,
    getCoreRowModel,
    flexRender,
    getGroupedRowModel,
    getExpandedRowModel,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";

type Asset = {
    name: string;
    year: number;
    amount: number;
};

export function App() {
    const columns: ColumnDef<Asset>[] = [
        {
            accessorKey: "name",
            header: "Name",
        },
        {
            accessorKey: "year",
            header: "Year",
        },
        {
            accessorKey: "amount",
            header: "Amount",
            aggregationFn: "sum",
        },
    ];
    
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        { name: "Item 1", year: 2022, amount: 31 },
        { name: "Item 2", year: 2022, amount: 4312 },
        { name: "Item 3", year: 2022, amount: 1233 },
        { name: "Item 4", year: 2024, amount: 123 },
        { name: "Item 5", year: 2024, amount: 512 },
    ]);

    const table = useReactTable({
        columns,
        data,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
        getGroupedRowModel: getGroupedRowModel(),
        getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
        state: {
            grouping: ["year"],
        },
    });

    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
                    <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                            <th key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
                                {header.isPlaceholder
                                    ? null
                                    : flexRender(header.column.columnDef.header, header.getContext())}
                            </th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                    <tr key={row.id}>
                        {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                            <td key={cell.id}>
                                {cell.getIsPlaceholder()
                                    ? null
                                    : flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                            </td>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The `cell` object includes methods such as `getIsGrouped()` and `getIsAggregated()` that you can use to style and or display as desired.

Here is an example of adding tailwind classNames to the `td`:

```
<td
  key={cell.id}
  className={
    cell.getIsGrouped() ? "bg-red-50" :
    cell.getIsAggregated() ? "bg-orange-50" :
    cell.getIsPlaceholder() ? "bg-blue-50" :
    ""}
  >
   {cell.getIsPlaceholder()
     ? null
     : flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
</td>
```

The same methods can be used to decide how to render the content inside the td as well—for example to add a count to the end of the value display.

An example can be found here: https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/react/grouping